# In Dajaxice (Django), how do you specify a GET vs a POST?

Tags: python, ajax, django, dajaxice

It seems in [Dajaxice](http://www.dajaxproject.com/) that everything is a POST. I've read that it's not good practice to mix up GET and POST and I think I know when to use which one.

So how do I specify a GET request in Dajaxice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see that [here](http://django-dajaxice.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#how-can-i-do-a-get-request-instead-of-a-post-one)

GET method is defined in registration decorator:

```
@dajaxice_register(method='GET')
```